# Implementing Union-Find, getting TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, algorithm, union-find

I am trying to implement a quick-union with path compression algorithm and for some reason I'm getting a `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` when testing. It all looks good to me. Here's the code; I appreciate your help.

Here's the full error, followed by the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quick-find.py", line 75, in <module>
    a.union(7,9)
  File "quick-find.py", line 56, in union
    node2_root = self.root(node2)
  File "quick-find.py", line 47, in root
    self.id[node] = self.id[id[node]]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

```
class weightedQuickUnion:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.id = list(range(n))
        self.size = list([1]) * n

    def root( self, node ):
        # Improved to make every node point to its parent
            # This improvement makes it weightedQuickUnionWithPathCompression
        while ( node != self.id[node]):
            self.id[node] = self.id[id[node]]
            node = self.id[node]
        return node

    def connected(self, node1, node2):
        return self.id[node1] == self.id[node2]

    def union(self, node1, node2):
        node1_root = self.root(node1)
        node2_root = self.root(node2)
        if node1_root == node2_root:
            return
        if (self.size[node1_root] < self.size[node2_root]):
            self.id[node1_root] = node2_root
            self.size[node2_root] += self.size[node1_root]
        else:
            self.id[node2_root] = node1_root
            self.size[node1_root] += self.size[node2_root]

a = weightedQuickUnion(10)
print(a.id)
print(a.size)
print(a.connected(3,4))
a.union(3,4)
a.union(1,3)
a.union(6,9) 
print(a.id)
print(a.size)
a.union(7,9) # <-- this line throws an exception and I can't figure out why.
a.union(8,9)
```

Comment: You should show the full traceback. But this code in `root` feels like the culprit: `self.id[id[node]]`; what is `id[node]` supposed to be? What is that meant to do?

Comment: Daniel Roseman I think I added the full traceback exactly when you commented this, and you are right. However, I can't figure out why the other calls to `union()` succeed while this one fails.

Comment: `id` is a built-in function, entirely unrelated to your `self.id`.

Comment: @jasonharper THANK YOU. I'm new to python and I knew this was something simple.

Comment: Because that's the first time you've called the method with a node value you've used before (9). The first time you use any value, the while condition in `root` is false, so that block is not executed. But directly afterwards in `union` the id for that node is changed, which means the second time you call with that value the condition will be true and the while block will execute, hitting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jasonharper for pointing out that I dropped the "self." from the following line:

```
self.id[node] = self.id[id[node]]
```

Instead, it should be this:

```
self.id[node] = self.id[self.id[node]]
```